# How to skip neighboring points while placing instances using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have created a 3D point grid via using *Volume Cube Node* and *Distribute Points in Volume Node*. But I do not want to put spheres on each point, rather I would like to skip each neighboring point. Kind of like in the attached ss.[image]

I am really new into blender and even putting the question in right manner is difficult, so I could not find a solution for this. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: "skip each neighboring point" - you want a 3D checkerboard of empty cell / cell with a sphere?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady that is correct I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my math knowledge left me right now...

i don't get it.

you can achieve your wish with this node setup:

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

BUT...
if i change the spacing to .3 and demute the divide node...it doesn't work.

i have no idea why...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Chris, this is great, I will try to figure out that spacing issue. If I can solve it, I'll let you know.  Also, I have come up with the idea using checker texture which you can see below.

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with the following solution (inspired by the comment of @MarkusvonBroady) , using *Checker Texture* and it works as I want when the scale is around 3.5, I don't know why this number. I am going to check its scalability and update here if it works.
[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution, I would just reprogram the checker texture myself forgetting it's availabie in geonodes. :)

Comment: Thanks, I still don't know how it exactly works but with couple of trial and errors on sockets it worked, I was lucky :)

Comment: good solution!! +1